# D3.select ID returning null despite existing element with ID

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to select based on ID for various elements in a force-directed graph. I am able to select a node and it's label based on their ID without issue, but when I try to select a link it just returns null like so - (at *'s)

```
ut {_groups: Array(1), _parents: Array(1)}
_groups: Array(1)
0: Array(1)
****0: null****
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
_parents: [html]
__proto__: Object
```

However, when I log the ID that is being selected and compare it with elements in the inspector, there are elements with the exact matching ID that is being selected on. For example, the link will `d3.select("#P DataIns")` and if I inspect the link between P data and Ins, it shows `<line id="P DataIns"></line>`

```
            var childNode = d3.select("#" + checkingNode.id);
            childNode.style("opacity", 1);
            childNode.style("stroke", highlight_color);

            var childLink = d3.select("#" + node2.id + checkingNode.id);
            childLink.style("opacity", 1);
            childLink.style("stroke", highlight_color);

            var childLabel = d3.select("#" + checkingNode.id + "label");
            childLabel.style("opacity", 1);
            childLabel.style("font-weight", "bold");
```

This is the code I use for selecting, only the middle code for selecting child link doesn't work. Is there something I'm doing wrong in this one different from the other two that would cause this? All IDs only use letters or spaces. For reference the links are created as follows -

```
link = link.data(config.links, d => d.id);
    link.exit().remove();
    link = link.enter().append("line")
            .attr("id", function (d) {
                return d.source + d.target;
            })
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("stroke", "#888")
            .merge(link);
```

I've reviewed [Mike Bostocks article](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/) for how selections work, and it seems to me like this should be working...

Comment: IDs must not contain space characters! Furthermore, your selector `" #P DataIns"` will select the **child** element of type `<DataIns>` of the element having ID `P`, which is not what you want. You'll have to revise your IDs first to get the results you are after.

Comment: The IDs of the nodes contain space characters without causing issues, and their selections are formed in the same way as the link selections with no problem (eg. to select node P Data -> `d3.select("#P Data");`  I will try removing the spaces though, thanks!

Comment: Still, it is wrong (see the SVG spec which refers to https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Names). And these wrong IDs are the cause for your problems. `d3.select("#P DataIns")` matches `<line id="P"><DataIns/></line>`, not the expected `<line id="P DataIns">`.

Comment: Removing all spaces seems to have fixed it but I don't understand how it worked for the nodes just fine but not the links...And now I'm having an entirely different issue regarding `d3.style` not updating the `style="stroke:RGB"` but instead the `<line>` elements `stroke` attribute resulting in no change...ugh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of the comments, I have found that the issue was due to the ID's of the links having spaces in them. However, the nodes also had spaces in, and worked just fine.

Regardless, the way I solved this for anyone coming along later was by simply adding

```
.replace(/\s/g, '')
```

when the ID's were loaded from the JSON data, to remove any white space, and selecting the links started working.